# Oracle alphanumeric sorting

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have my data something like this

```
select x FROM (
select 'OUTDR1004' x from dual union all
select 'CXL10570' x from dual union all
select 'OUTDR904' x from dual union all 
select '213OUTD' x from dual union all 
select '1111111111231' x from dual 
) order by case when regexp_like(x,'^[[:digit:]]') then LPAD(x,50, '0') else x end;
```

Order by gives me data in the following order

```
213OUTD
1111111111231
CXL10570
OUTDR1004
OUTDR904
```

But I want my data in the following order

```
213OUTD
1111111111231
CXL10570
OUTDR904
OUTDR1004
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please explain the logics behind your need?

Comment: because OUTDR904 is smaller than OUTDR1004.

Comment: You've got some values starting with numbers, some ending with numbers, and others are all numbers.  My feeling is that you should fix your data model and stop mixing numeric and text data.

Comment: can't do that, this is how their business is :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like what you want to do is a compound sort - you want to sort alphabetic characters alphabetically, but you want numeric characters to be grouped together and treated as numbers.

```
select x
FROM (
select '144' x from dual union all
select '211' x from dual union all
select '211B' x from dual union all 
select '207AB' x from dual union all 
select '213OUTD' x from dual  union all 
select '1111111111231' x from dual union all
select 'OUTDR1004' x from dual union all
select 'CXL10570' x from dual union all
select 'OUTDR904' x from dual
) order by case
    -- starts with number, pad number part with zeros to sort numerically
    when regexp_like(x,'^[[:digit:]]') then lpad(regexp_substr(x, '^[[:digit:]]+'),50,'0')  
    -- if x starts with non-numeric, primary sort the alpha portion
    when regexp_like(x, '^[^[:digit:]]') then regexp_substr(x, '^[^[:digit:]]+') 
    else x end,
   -- if x starts with a non-numeric, secondary sort by the numeric portion (zero padded)
   case when regexp_like(x, '^[^[:digit:]]') then lpad(regexp_substr(x, '[[:digit:]]+$'),50,'0')
     -- if x starts with a numeric, secondary sort by the alpha portion
     when regexp_like(x, '^[[:digit:]]') then regexp_substr(x, '[^[:digit:]]+$')
     else x end nulls first;
```

Hopefully you just have the cases you showed here, and don't have cases like `302OUTDR378`, or else this sorting logic will quickly get unmanageable.

Edit: updated to stop including the alpha portion in the 0-padding.

Edit 2: updated to add 'nulls first' to secondary sort.

Comment: If I have data like this `OUTDR1004,CXL10570,OUTDR904,213OUTD,206,207AB,211,144` and I want this to be sorted like `144,206,207AB,211,213OUTD,CXL10570,OUTDR904,OUTDR1004`. Currently 207AB appears after 211, but what I want this to appear immediately after 206.

Comment: If I have 211B in data and I want it after 211. Currently the sorting is like 211B, 211. I want is 211, 211B.
Thanks

Comment: Edited again, added "nulls first" to secondary sort.